# stax to DOM converter

Tags: java

I want to  read DOM document using Stax stream readers and write it using Stax stream writers.
I want to modify xml file and change some element values
I want the cursor to point at a certain element in xml file befor building dom tree
I wrote this code but the xml file did not modified
can anybody help me ?

FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("cv.xml");
        XMLStreamReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(input);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

```
    //-*-*- get new entries from input stream
    System.out.println("<< CV >>\n -> Modify the first reference\n    ** Modify The Name **");
    System.out.print("    Enter degree : ");
    String degree = in.readLine();
    System.out.print("    Enter first name : ");
    String fName = in.readLine();
    System.out.print("    Enter last name : ");
    String lName = in.readLine();
    System.out.println("    ** Modify The Address ** ");
    System.out.print("    Enter new city : ");
    String newCity = in.readLine();
    System.out.print("    Enter new country : ");
    String newCountry = in.readLine();

    //-*-*- let the reader point at the first "reference" element
    int eventType;
    boolean ref = false, fname = false;
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        eventType = reader.next();
        switch (eventType) {
            case XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT:
                if (reader.getLocalName().equalsIgnoreCase("references"))
                    return;
        }
    }
    //-*-*- build DOM trees using Stax stream reader
    Document doc = new DOMConverter().buildDocument(reader);
    reader.close();
    input.close();
    //-*-*- start modification
    Element firstRef = (Element)doc.getElementsByTagName("reference").item(0);
    NodeList name = (NodeList)firstRef.getElementsByTagName("name");
    //-*-*- modify the degree (Dr. , Eng. , Dev. ,etc)
    Attr att = (Attr)name.item(0).getAttributes().item(0);
    ((Node)att).setNodeValue(degree);
    //-*-*- modify first name
    NodeList firstName = (NodeList)firstRef.getElementsByTagName("fname");
    NodeList firstNameChilds = (NodeList)firstName.item(0).getChildNodes();
    ((Node)firstNameChilds.item(0)).setNodeValue(fName);
    //-*-*- modify last name
    NodeList lastName = (NodeList)firstRef.getElementsByTagName("lname");
    NodeList lastNameChilds = (NodeList)lastName.item(0).getChildNodes();
    ((Node)lastNameChilds.item(0)).setNodeValue(lName);
    //-*-*- modify city
    NodeList city = (NodeList)firstRef.getElementsByTagName("city");
    NodeList cityChilds = (NodeList)city.item(0).getChildNodes();
    ((Node)cityChilds.item(0)).setNodeValue(newCity);
    //-*-*- modify country
    NodeList country = (NodeList)firstRef.getElementsByTagName("country");
    NodeList countryChilds = (NodeList)country.item(0).getChildNodes();
    ((Node)countryChilds.item(0)).setNodeValue(newCountry);

    //-*-*- write DOM document
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("cv.xml");
    XMLStreamWriter sw = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamWriter(out);

    new DOMConverter().writeDocument(doc, sw);
    sw.close();
    out.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because you are returning when you find the "references" element. Maybe `break` is what you meant.

Comment: no, I meant return, I want to stop while loop when the XMLStreamReader match "references" element.  so, the dom tree begin from this element

Comment: Return will exit out of the entire method. I'm pretty sure you want `break` to get out of that while loop. Try putting some debugging statements after that loop and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: yes you are right about return but when I use break it will get out of switch but still in the loop after the cursor match references element and will reach the end of the document

Comment: Right, so you need a better loop control variable. Try a boolean that is false at the beginning and set to true when you find `references`. You will still need to check for `reader.hasNext()`.

Comment: I tried this :int eventType;
        boolean ref = false, fname = false;
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            eventType = reader.next();
            switch (eventType) {
                case XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT:
                    if (reader.getLocalName().equalsIgnoreCase("references")) {
                        ref = true;
                        break;
                    }
            }
           if(ref)
               break;
        }
        System.out.println("I am here");

Comment: but it threw two exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/stax2/ri/Stax2ReaderAdapter

Comment: Looks better. You could also do `while (!ref && reader.hasNext())` to make it a bit more succinct.

Comment: and java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.stax2.ri.Stax2ReaderAdapter                             it's the first time I use Dom converter, I don't know where I write a peroper code or not

Comment: OK, the exceptions are probably a bit beyond the scope of this question. Try searching for similar questions and see if someone else has had the same problem.